# I can't see any wireless setting in loki 0.4. Please help!

Tags: wifi

[image]
There isn't any wifi setting, and i am a noob, dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Now, it will be good to provide some troubleshooting info so we are able to help.
To me it sounds that Loki is trying to load incorrect driver for your wifi hence the issue. 
You need to discover the manufacturer of your [wifi](/questions/tagged/wifi) card, and discover what driver Loki is trying to load. For example if you have Intel wireless card and Loki is trying to load Acer drivers will result in wifi card blockage.

Here you go few commands to help us troubleshoot. Please provide output of this commands and/if by issuing this commands your wifi started working. We should be able to take from there if further assistance is necessary:

`iwconfig` - to find your wifi interface name (e.g *wlan0*)

`rfkill list all` - to see whether your interface is blocked, hardware block or software block (here you may see different wireless vendor instead of the actual one which indicates and issue)

`ifconfig wlan0 up` - trying to bring the interface up

`lspci` - find the hardware manufacturer

`lshw -C network` - find the manufacturer of your wifi card

`nmcli radio wifi on`  - try to bring the interface up

`killall NetworkManager && NetworkManager` - kill existing network manager process

`/etc/init.d/network-manager reload` - reload service

`/etc/init.d/networking restart` - reload tcp/ip stack

Comment: Thx for this! The *nmcli radio wifi on* worked for me, after i searched around on many webpages. Stupid thing is, the Wifi-USB-dongle was recognized...the kernel module was loaded...but **switchboard-plug-networking** gives me "Wifi is disabled" but the switch on the top right was on. Strange thing...now working :D

Answer (score 1):

You may not have the the necessary Wifi drivers. You need to:

1. Find the wifi adapter your pc/laptop is having.
2. Find if its driver is available (just search with adapter_name + ubuntu + driver on google)
3. You will likely get good tutorials to install the driver.

We you can provide specifics, I can update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect your pc with terhering cable with mobile ( must internet connection) open app store then uinstall updated kernal version the restart your pc done.