# How do I install RTL8723BE driver in Elementary OS (4.13.0-41)?

Tags: release-loki, wifi, software-installation, drivers, hp

I've installed Elementary OS on HP [15-bw011dx](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05666796) (UEFI/GPT, Secure boot OFF). Ethernet works but the wireless nic does not appear in SYSTEM SETTINGS/NETWORK.

In a terminal I entered the following command per [these](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8743/i-cant-see-any-wireless-setting-in-loki-0-4-please-help) instructions:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

The terminal returned the identification of my ethernet adapter (RTL8111/8168/8411), etc and its status. It went on to describe my wireless nic in this way:

```
fff
*-network UNCLAIMED
```

It recognized the controller as Realtek. Laptop driver download (Win) page is [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-15-bw000-laptop-pc/15551418/model/17850904).

I followed [these](http://nealbuerger.com/2018/02/things-to-do-after-installing-elementary-os-0-4-1-loki/) instructions so I could add the ppa named in [these](https://akshaycv006.wordpress.com/2017/01/12/installing-realtek-rtl8723be-driver-for-ubuntu-debian-or-fedora/) instructions. So in order I entered the following commands into a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

I then restarted and still the wireless adaptor is absent from SYSTEM SETTINGS/NETWORK and the interface still appears "UNCLAIMED".

According to [these](https://akshaycv006.wordpress.com/2017/01/12/installing-realtek-rtl8723be-driver-for-ubuntu-debian-or-fedora/) instructions I should issue the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) gcc g++ build-essential dkms git
sudo reboot
cd rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
```

However, on entering the third command:

```
cd rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex
```

I get

```
bash: cd: rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex: No such file or directory
```

To recap: I would like to install the driver for Realtek RTL8723BE in Elementary OS (HP 15-bw011dx).